# Why when I use the excel vba code below there is runtime error 1004 and else without if?

Tags: excel, vba

```vb
Sub Result()

barang = ActiveSheet.Columns(5)

If InStr("barang", "*SF*") <> 0 Then _
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[-2]<25,IF(RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'Price List SF'!R4C1:R27C7,6,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<55,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List SF'!R4C1:R27C7,4,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]>=60,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List SF'!R4C1:R27C7,2,FALSE),1%,0.5%),"""")))"

ElseIf InStr("barang", "BS" & "FS") <> 0 Then _
       ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
         "=IF(RC[-2]<5,IF(RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'Harga Bubble & Foam'!R5C1:R12C7,6,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<10,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Harga Bubble & Foam'!R5C1:R12C7,4,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]>=10,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Harga Bubble & Foam'!R5C1:R12C7,2,FALSE),1%,0.5%),"""")))"


ElseIf InStr("barang", "SB") <> 0 Then _
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[-2]<30,IF(RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'Harga Strapping Band RajaPack'!R4C1:R27C7,6,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<100,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Harga Strapping Band RajaPack'!R4C1:R27C7,4,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]>=100,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Harga Strapping Band RajaPack'!R4C1:R27C7,2,FALSE),1%,0.5%),"""")))"


ElseIf InStr("barang", "MT" & "DT" & "KT" & "CT") <> 0 Then ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'Price List MT, DT, KT, CT'!R4C1:R28C8,2,FALSE)=72,IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<360,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List MT, DT, KT, CT'!R4C1:R28C8,7,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<720,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List MT, DT, KT, CT'!R4C1:R28C8,5,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]>=720,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price L" & _
        "ist MT, DT, KT, CT'!R4C1:R28C8,3,FALSE),1%,0.5%),""""))),IF(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List MT, DT, KT, CT'!R4C1:R28C8,2,FALSE)=144,IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<720,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List MT, DT, KT, CT'!R4C1:R28C8,7,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<1440,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List MT, DT, KT, CT'!R4C1:R28C8,5,FALSE),1%,0.5%);IF(She" & _
        "et1!RC[-2]>=1440,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List MT, DT, KT, CT'!R4C1:R28C8,3,FALSE),1%,0.5%)))),IF(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List MT, DT, KT, CT'!R4C1:R28C8,2,FALSE)=288,IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<1440,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List MT, DT, KT, CT'!R4C1:R28C8,7,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<2880,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'P" & _
        "rice List MT, DT, KT, CT'!R4C1:R28C8,5,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]>=2880,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List MT, DT, KT, CT'!R4C1:R28C8,3,FALSE),1%,0.5%)))),"""")))"


Else


       ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,2,FALSE)=12,IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<60,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,7,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<120,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,5,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]>=120,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'! " & _
        "R4C1:R42C8,3,FALSE),1%,0.5%),""""))),IF(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,2,FALSE)=48,IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<240,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,7,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<480,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,5,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]>=480,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=" & _
        "VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,3,FALSE),1%,0.5%),""""))),IF(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,2,FALSE)=72,IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<360,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,7,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<720,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,5,FALSE),1%" & _
        "(Sheet1!RC[-2]>=720,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,3,FALSE),1%,0.5%),""""))),IF(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,2,FALSE)=144,IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<720,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,7,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<1440,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3]," & _
        "'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,5,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]>=1440,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,3,FALSE),1%,0.5%),""""))),IF(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,2,FALSE)=288,IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<1440,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,7,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<" & _
        "2880;IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,5,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]>=2880,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,3,FALSE),1%,0.5%),""""))))))))"
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the `_` after your `Then` statements.

Comment: I tried, but the vba won't read my code

Comment: it just skips the formula which is the value_if_true

Comment: all of your `instr` statements will **always** return false as you are not using any variable, but the literal string `"barang"`

Comment: @GeertBellekens This is the first code here, I am currently trying to repair the edited code at the bottom because Excel didn't read the formula as instructed and instead skipped them and also the runtime error 1004 on the formula after Else

Answer (score 1):

Right, so as mentioned in comments, if you `Debug` your code you will see the same error `Else Without If`. This is because you are using the `_` incorrectly. Again, using an underscore is effectively allowing you to write multiple lines of code which effectively is one. This is used for "splitting" very long individual lines. I have updated your code below with some minor adjustments. I haven't tested it but it is compiling.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Result()

    Dim barang As Range

    Set barang = ActiveSheet.Columns(5)

    If InStr("barang", "*SF*") <> 0 Then
       ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IF(RC[-2]<25,IF(RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'Price List SF'!R4C1:R27C7,6,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<55,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List SF'!R4C1:R27C7,4,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]>=60,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List SF'!R4C1:R27C7,2,FALSE),1%,0.5%),"""")))"

    ElseIf InStr("barang", "BS" & "FS") <> 0 Then
           ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
             "=IF(RC[-2]<5,IF(RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'Harga Bubble & Foam'!R5C1:R12C7,6,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<10,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Harga Bubble & Foam'!R5C1:R12C7,4,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]>=10,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Harga Bubble & Foam'!R5C1:R12C7,2,FALSE),1%,0.5%),"""")))"


    ElseIf InStr("barang", "SB") <> 0 Then
     ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IF(RC[-2]<30,IF(RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'Harga Strapping Band RajaPack'!R4C1:R27C7,6,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<100,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Harga Strapping Band RajaPack'!R4C1:R27C7,4,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]>=100,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Harga Strapping Band RajaPack'!R4C1:R27C7,2,FALSE),1%,0.5%),"""")))"


    ElseIf InStr("barang", "MT" & "DT" & "KT" & "CT") <> 0 Then
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IF(VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'Price List MT, DT, KT, CT'!R4C1:R28C8,2,FALSE)=72,IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<360,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List MT, DT, KT, CT'!R4C1:R28C8,7,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<720,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List MT, DT, KT, CT'!R4C1:R28C8,5,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]>=720,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price L" & _
            "ist MT, DT, KT, CT'!R4C1:R28C8,3,FALSE),1%,0.5%),""""))),IF(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List MT, DT, KT, CT'!R4C1:R28C8,2,FALSE)=144,IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<720,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List MT, DT, KT, CT'!R4C1:R28C8,7,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<1440,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List MT, DT, KT, CT'!R4C1:R28C8,5,FALSE),1%,0.5%);IF(She" & _
            "et1!RC[-2]>=1440,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List MT, DT, KT, CT'!R4C1:R28C8,3,FALSE),1%,0.5%)))),IF(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List MT, DT, KT, CT'!R4C1:R28C8,2,FALSE)=288,IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<1440,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List MT, DT, KT, CT'!R4C1:R28C8,7,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<2880,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'P" & _
            "rice List MT, DT, KT, CT'!R4C1:R28C8,5,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]>=2880,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List MT, DT, KT, CT'!R4C1:R28C8,3,FALSE),1%,0.5%)))),"""")))"


    Else
           ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IF(VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,2,FALSE)=12,IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<60,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,7,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<120,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,5,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]>=120,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'! " & _
            "R4C1:R42C8,3,FALSE),1%,0.5%),""""))),IF(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,2,FALSE)=48,IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<240,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,7,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<480,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,5,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]>=480,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=" & _
            "VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,3,FALSE),1%,0.5%),""""))),IF(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,2,FALSE)=72,IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<360,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,7,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<720,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,5,FALSE),1%" & _
            "(Sheet1!RC[-2]>=720,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,3,FALSE),1%,0.5%),""""))),IF(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,2,FALSE)=144,IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<720,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,7,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<1440,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3]," & _
            "'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,5,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]>=1440,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,3,FALSE),1%,0.5%),""""))),IF(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,2,FALSE)=288,IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<1440,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,7,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<" & _
            "2880;IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,5,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]>=2880,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,3,FALSE),1%,0.5%),""""))))))))"
    End If


End Sub
```

---

**EDIT**

Right, so you are missing a `For` loop in your code, so I think what you are looking for is below. I have not tested it but I am sure you will get the logic.

Also, it is good coding practice to explicitly define your worksheet objects because using `ActiveSheet` is prone to user error.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Result()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, lRow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    lRow = ws.Columns(5).Rows.Count


    For i = 1 To lRow

        With ws.Cells(i, 5)

            If InStr(1, .Value, "*SF*") <> 0 Then
               .FormulaR1C1 = _
                "=IF(RC[-2]<25,IF(RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'Price List SF'!R4C1:R27C7,6,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<55,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List SF'!R4C1:R27C7,4,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]>=60,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List SF'!R4C1:R27C7,2,FALSE),1%,0.5%),"""")))"

            ElseIf InStr(1, .Value, "BS") <> 0 Then
                .FormulaR1C1 = _
                "=IF(RC[-2]<5,IF(RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'Harga Bubble & Foam'!R5C1:R12C7,6,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<10,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Harga Bubble & Foam'!R5C1:R12C7,4,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]>=10,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Harga Bubble & Foam'!R5C1:R12C7,2,FALSE),1%,0.5%),"""")))"


            ElseIf InStr(1, .Value, "SB") <> 0 Then
                .FormulaR1C1 = _
                "=IF(RC[-2]<30,IF(RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'Harga Strapping Band RajaPack'!R4C1:R27C7,6,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<100,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Harga Strapping Band RajaPack'!R4C1:R27C7,4,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]>=100,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Harga Strapping Band RajaPack'!R4C1:R27C7,2,FALSE),1%,0.5%),"""")))"


            ElseIf InStr(1, .Value, "MT") <> 0 Then
                .FormulaR1C1 = _
                "=IF(VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'Price List MT, DT, KT, CT'!R4C1:R28C8,2,FALSE)=72,IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<360,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List MT, DT, KT, CT'!R4C1:R28C8,7,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<720,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List MT, DT, KT, CT'!R4C1:R28C8,5,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]>=720,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price L" & _
                "ist MT, DT, KT, CT'!R4C1:R28C8,3,FALSE),1%,0.5%),""""))),IF(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List MT, DT, KT, CT'!R4C1:R28C8,2,FALSE)=144,IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<720,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List MT, DT, KT, CT'!R4C1:R28C8,7,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<1440,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List MT, DT, KT, CT'!R4C1:R28C8,5,FALSE),1%,0.5%);IF(She" & _
                "et1!RC[-2]>=1440,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List MT, DT, KT, CT'!R4C1:R28C8,3,FALSE),1%,0.5%)))),IF(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List MT, DT, KT, CT'!R4C1:R28C8,2,FALSE)=288,IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<1440,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List MT, DT, KT, CT'!R4C1:R28C8,7,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<2880,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'P" & _
                "rice List MT, DT, KT, CT'!R4C1:R28C8,5,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]>=2880,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List MT, DT, KT, CT'!R4C1:R28C8,3,FALSE),1%,0.5%)))),"""")))"

            Else
                .FormulaR1C1 = _
                 "=IF(VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,2,FALSE)=12,IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<60,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,7,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<120,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,5,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]>=120,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'! " & _
                 "R4C1:R42C8,3,FALSE),1%,0.5%),""""))),IF(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,2,FALSE)=48,IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<240,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,7,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<480,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,5,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]>=480,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=" & _
                 "VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,3,FALSE),1%,0.5%),""""))),IF(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,2,FALSE)=72,IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<360,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,7,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<720,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,5,FALSE),1%" & _
                 "(Sheet1!RC[-2]>=720,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,3,FALSE),1%,0.5%),""""))),IF(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,2,FALSE)=144,IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<720,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,7,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<1440,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3]," & _
                 "'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,5,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]>=1440,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,3,FALSE),1%,0.5%),""""))),IF(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,2,FALSE)=288,IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<1440,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,7,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]<" & _
                 "2880;IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,5,FALSE),1%,0.5%),IF(Sheet1!RC[-2]>=2880,IF(Sheet1!RC[-1]>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!RC[-3],'Price List OPP Tapes'!R4C1:R42C8,3,FALSE),1%,0.5%),""""))))))))"
            End If

        End With

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, but Excel still skips the formula after I debug it, but the else without if problem is solved

Comment: So, I tried using your code, Dean. I used debug and after Then, excel skips the value if true(in this case the formula if true) and moves on to the next if, and there is also a runtime error 1004 on the last formula after Else

Comment: @LLawliet are you trying to find the string in the given column?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to find it

Comment: a string which  has a partial match with the criteria that I've given in the given column

Comment: @LLawliet I have edited my answer above. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but when I tested it Excel still doesn't read the

Comment: the formula which is the value if true. And I forgot to mention one thing, please check the last formula which is after Else. It has a runtime error 1004. Thanks for the help by the way. Thanks to you, we made great progress.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble

Comment: The fourth partial match has 4 criteria, if it matches these, it will return true